# Load Entities with Relationsships Neo4jClient

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I have a Neo4J Graph-Database with the following entities:

(game)-[:has]->(gamePlayerMapping)-[:mappingFor]->Player

So in fact I have an entity game and an entity player. And there is a many to many relationsship between those entities.

The entity GamePlayerMapping can be linked to other entities too. That's why it has to be a node itself.

In my c# code I have three corresponding classes:

- Game.cs
- Player.cs
- GamePlayerMapping.cs

Now I want to load a game with all corresponding gamePlayerMappings and the corresponding Players.

Using Neo4JClient, this is what my query-code looks like:

```
var x = _client.Cypher
            .Match("(game:Game {GameId: '" + id + "'})")
            .OptionalMatch("(game)-[has]->(gamePlayerMapping:GamePlayerMapping)-[:mappingFor]->(player:Player)")
            .Return((game, gamePlayerMapping, player) => new
            {
                Game = game.As<Game>(),
                Mappings = gamePlayerMapping.CollectAs<GamePlayerMapping>(),
                Players = player.CollectAs<Player>(),
            }
            )
            .Results;
```

The query works fine and I get an Object with the following properties:

- a Game-Object
- a List of GamePlayerMapping-Objects
- a List of Player-Objects

So here is my question:

How do I know which Player-Objects from the Players-List belongs to which GamePlayerMapping from the corresponding list?

Can I just assume that player at index 0 belongs to mapping at index 0 and so on? Sound dirty to me.

And of course this approach would not work any more, if a had a situation like this:

(entity1)-[:hasMany]->(entity2)-[:hasMany]->(entity3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got 3 approaches, none of which are amazeballs.

### 1. Split into two

In this one, get the game first, then the mappings subsequently:

```
var gameQuery = new CypherFluentQuery(_client)
    .Match("(g:Game {GameId: 1})")
    .Return(g => g.As<Game>());

var mappingQuery = new CypherFluentQuery(_client)
    .Match("(g:Game {GameId: 1})")
    .OptionalMatch("(g)-[:has]->(gpm:GamePlayerMapping)-[:mappingFor]->(p:Player)")
    .Return((gpm, p) => new
    {
        Mappings = gpm.As<GamePlayerMapping>(),
        Players = p.CollectAs<Player>()
    });
```

This gives you the mappings and players grouped as you'd expect.

**Negatives**

- The obvious - two queries - one to get the `Game` and another to get it's players etc.

**Positives**

- It's easy to know the mapping/player pairing/grouping.

### 2. Don't `CollectAs`

Basically, take your query, but remove the `CollectAs` bits:

```
var query = new CypherFluentQuery(Client)
    .Match("(g:Game {GameId: 1})")
    .OptionalMatch("(g)-[:has]->(gpm:GamePlayerMapping)-[:mappingFor]->(p:Player)")
    .Return((g, gpm, p) => new
    {
        Game = g.As<Game>(),
        Mapping = gpm.As<GamePlayerMapping>(),
        Player = p.As<Player>()
    });
```

**Negatives**

- You return `Game` n times, which is an overhead.
- You have to parse the results into a format you can use.

**Positives**

- Without the `CollectAs` each `Mapping`, `Player` pairing is joined, so you know that they match.

### 3. Add a 'PlayerIds' collection to the `GamePlayerMapping`

You can still do your original query, but parse the results into the format you want by being able to pull the player Ids from the Mapping.

**Negatives**

- You have to edit your actual class, and then make sure when you add a player that you add the mapping, ensure that the mapping list is kept up to date, etc etc

**Positives**

- Well - you can work out which mapping had which player.

---

A lot would come down to the sort of performance you need. The first option I think is the least bad, but you might find the 2 calls to be too much. The second option is one query, but returns `Game` n times, so for 3 players, you get the game back 3 times, and for the mapping you'd get it back as many times as there are players in that mapping. So in terms of data going over the wire - it's not very efficient.

The third option whilst best for data over the wire - would be problematic and is far more complicated to ensure it's always right.

Personally I'd choose option 1 **:/**

Comment: Thanks Chris. For now I'll take the first approach and see how this affects the performance of the application.